# Request was not matched when using Wiremock (testing requests to an external server)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, wiremock

I have configured several stubs using wiremock. I need to check a client that sends a request to an external server via the Rest API. But when I configured the stubs, then for some reason the request when it comes to the stub is truncated and the host (simulating an external server) is truncated.

[image]

application.properties

```sh
api.url.fail.header.rec.count.external.server=http://127.0.0.1:8282/dataByUnloadPlanPaysSet/failRecCount
```

- rest-client

```java
    public ResponseEntity<InfoFromExternalServerDto>
    sendRequestFromExternalServer(String blockId, String urlToExternalServer) {

        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = buildUriToExternalServer(blockId, urlToExternalServer);
        String uriWithParamsToExternalServer = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();

        HttpHeaders requestHttpHeaders = getHeadersHttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<Object> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, requestHttpHeaders);

        return restTemplate.exchange(
                uriWithParamsToExternalServer,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                requestHttpEntity,
                InfoFromExternalServerDto.class
        );
    }


    private UriComponentsBuilder buildUriToExternalServer(String blockId, String urlToExternalServer) {

        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlToExternalServer)
                .queryParam("format", "json")
                .queryParam("block", blockId);
    }

    private HttpHeaders getHeadersHttpHeaders() {

        var requestHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHttpHeaders.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        return requestHttpHeaders;
    }
```

- wiremock configure

```java
@Value("${api.url.fail.header.rec.count.external.server}")
    private String apiUrlFailHeaderRecCountToExternalServer;


    public void setupStubForProcessingRequest(int portExternalServerMock) {

        String addressHost = "127.0.0.1";

        configureFor(addressHost, portExternalServerMock);

        setupResponseInCaseFailRecCount();
    }

    private void setupResponseInCaseFailRecCount(){

        String countEntriesIntoHeaderRecCount = "1";

        UrlPattern urlPattern = urlEqualTo(this.apiUrlFailHeaderRecCountToExternalServer);

        MappingBuilder mappingBuilder = get(urlPattern);

        MappingBuilder mappingBuilderWithHeader = serverMockUtils.makeMappingBuilderSuccess(mappingBuilder);

        int statusOk = HttpStatus.OK.value();

        ResponseDefinitionBuilder responseDefinitionBuilder = aResponse().
                withStatus(statusOk)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withHeader("rec_count", countEntriesIntoHeaderRecCount)
                .withBodyFile("json/infoFromExternalServer.json");

        MappingBuilder responseForReturn = mappingBuilderWithHeader.willReturn(responseDefinitionBuilder);

        stubFor(responseForReturn);
    }

 public MappingBuilder makeMappingBuilderSuccess(MappingBuilder mappingBuilder){

        return mappingBuilder
                .withHeader("Accept", matching("application/json"))
                .withQueryParam("format", equalTo("json"))
                .withQueryParam("block", equalTo(blockId));
    }
```

- test

```java
@Value("${api.url.fail.header.rec.count.external.server}")
    private String apiUrlFailHeaderRecCountToExternalServer;

    @Value("${blockId.param.query}")
    private String blockId;

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    private final int portExternalServerMock = 8282;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {

        WireMockConfiguration mockConfigurationPort = wireMockConfig()
                .port(this.portExternalServerMock);

        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(mockConfigurationPort);
        wireMockServer.start();

        restServerMockForClient.setupStubForProcessingRequest(this.portExternalServerMock) ;
    }

@AfterEach
    void teardown() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void getDataFromExternalServer() {
        InfoFromExternalServerDto dataFromExternalServer =
                clientToExternalServer.getDataFromExternalServer(this.blockId,
                        this.apiUrlFailHeaderRecCountToExternalServer);

       
    }
```

I have multiple configuration for hosts with different addresses. Each host has its own port. When I send a request via the endpoint Rest controller, then the host address is not truncated. If I call the method that calls the client from the test loop, then for some reason the host address is formed and the Wiremock stub cannot give a valid answer.

Please tell me what's going on. How can I **fix** this ?

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer to the question? It will make it easier for people searching in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

- application.properties

```sh
api.url.fail.header.rec.count.external.server=http://127.0.0.1:8282/dataByUnloadPlanPaysSet/failRecCount

api.url.fail.header.rec.count.for.stubs=/dataByUnloadPlanPaysSet/failRecCount
```

**api.url.fail.header.rec.count.for.stubs** - this address must be assigned when creating a stub (without specifying the host address and host port)

**It is important.**

Use the method - **urlPathEqualTo()**

```java
UrlPathPattern urlPathPattern = urlPathEqualTo(this.apiUrlFailHeaderRecCountToExternalServer);
```